# AzureML Studio - Unable to Export Data using Designer

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

- I built a classification model using the new AzureML Studio Designer. I am trying to export
  enter code herethe scored model as CSV file using the pill Export Data. I have selected
  workspaceblobstore as datastore and csv as file format. The pipeline runs fine, but the
  dataset does not show up under Data. I am also unable to just right-click on the scored model
  and download a csv file.*

```
[Pipeline][1]
[Export Data Parameters][2]
[Output][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlaec.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLwRv.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rua29.png
```

Answer (score 0):

When the dataset is uploaded using any of the following formats, we can see the dataset under the dataset of the designer tab.

[image]

[image]

To reproduce the problem, used a sample dataset and uploaded from the **local directory** in the form of CSV file. It validated perfectly under the **data** it is visible in **designer tab**